# static field initialization using AST

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to create a static String variable with a default value (e.g. public static final String COUNTRY="INDIA";) using Eclipse AST. I'm able to create such a varibale using SingleVariableDecleration or FieldDecleration. But I'm not sure how to initialize the same using AST.

*This is what I could implement*==>
public static final String COUNTRY;

*This is what I could not implement*==>
public static final String COUNTRY**="INDIA";**

Please help me to know how can I do this. Thanks in advance,

Shyam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a VariableDeclarationFragment in which you can specify the initializer. Then use this fragment to set FieldDeclaration.FRAGMENTS_PROPERTY.

You should use the [AST View plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php) to visualize the AST of Java source, this helps in creating the AST nodes for given source by hand which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. But the initializer would create a static block, right? Is there any way to do the same in oneline (public static String VAR ="VALUE") ?

Comment: If you use the AST view plugin you can see for yourself that 'country = "INDIA"' constitutes a VariableDeclarationFragment. => No initializer block is created, everything is on one line.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I have last acheived the thing. Ofcourse, with your help only. Thanks a ton!